# Display multiple data points in single chart

Tags: apache-zeppelin

scala :

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("Jan" , "1", "1","3"),
    ("Feb" , "2", "5","2"),
    ("Mar" , "2", "3","1")))
    .toDF("time" , "f1", "f2", "f3")

 df.registerTempTable("inout")
```

sql :

```
%sql 
select time , f1 , f2 , f3
from inout
```

But I would like to graph all data points on a single visualization , so three lines should be drawn where each line displays the points for f1,f2,f3. Currently just "f1" is displayed :

[image]

How to display all the data in single line chart ?

In other words how to display these three line charts as a single chart ? :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Items to be plotted can be dragged to keys/values areas :

[image]